# Converter coluna Varchar para Date sem perder os dados

Tags: mysql, data, varchar

Antes o banco de dados estava salvando a data em um campo varchar e no padrão Brasileiro (`dd/mm/YYYY`), então modifiquei os valores utilizando o código abaixo:

```
UPDATE tabela SET coluna= DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(coluna, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
WHERE coluna LIKE '__/__/____';
```

Nesse ponto funcionou perfeitamente, ficou no padrão `YYYY-mm-dd`, mas ao mudar de varchar para date ele acabou apagando todos os meus dados e preenchendo com `0000-00-00`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090231/how-to-convert-a-varchar-column-type-to-date-type-without-losing-the-dates

Comment: Eu tinha visto esse link @LeoCaracciolo mas pra mim fica inviável sair replicando todas pela grande quantidade de tabelas e colunas que tenho, mesmo assim obrigado!